# Keeping the Dual monitor application active in its current window

Tags: java, swing

I have developed an application in java swing where two instances have to be run, and I have specified in the code to run a particular instance on a specific screen via configurations. The issue I'm facing is that since it is set as full screen I cannot keep two windows active.
As per requirement I need to keep two windows active in two screens.
The function I used to achieve this is given below.

```
public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame )
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
    DisplayMode newDisplayMode;

    if( screen > -1 && screen < gs.length )
    {
        gs[screen].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else if( gs.length > 0 )
    {
        gs[0].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

Please can someone assist me to solve this issue.

Comment: That's an OS level restriction, you can't have two windows "active" at the same time, only one window can be "active" - or do you mean it switches out of "full screen exclusive" mode?

Comment: What about keeping the other window just displayed in my extended screen. For example we can drag and keep other applications we are running in the extended screen thereby keeping it visible.